# digital ocean server with simplehttpserver

Tags: python, html, server, hosting, simplehttpserver

I recently purchased a digital ocean ubuntu server and a go daddy domain. I have linked the two and booted up my server using python's SimpleHTTPServer.

The server will run fine for a few hours but as soon as I let my computer sleep or shut down the terminal that the ssh-agent is on, the server stops running.

I've tried including the '&' to make sure linux services it as a job but the problem is still there.

Maybe I have misunderstood HTTPServer's functionality, how can I boot up my server and host a source folder 24 / 7?

The command I have used to boot it up so far is;

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 &
```

Comment: I might be wrong but, I don't think Python server function is built for that purpose. Try using something like Nginx, Apache Tomcat or LAMP stack.

Comment: ahh so it really is a simple server, to test locally kind of thing. i'm not a huge fan of apache but i'll checkout the others, thanks !